# Window resize doesn't work after minimizing electron application to system tray

Tags: node.js, npm, electron

I'm currently working on wrapping a webpage using electron but I'm rather new to electron. I found code that has the exact function I was looking for: minimize to system tray =>

```
mainWindow.on('minimize', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
     mainWindow.hide()
});
```

Ater adding it, I noticed that when I restore the application from the tray and try to resize the window, the frame resizes but the content inside does not. Before minimizing, the content resizes perfectly. Not sure where this is breaking window resize, but I appreciate any help in advanced. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, it's hard to say without seeing enough code to reproduce your issue. For testing purposes, I just put together a basic electron app which wraps a web page and which minimizes to the system tray. When I restore it, I can resize the window and the content resizes accordingly. I could post that code as an answer (and a starting point for you) if you fancy, or you could update your question with enough code to reproduce. Oh yeah, I'm on Linux.

Comment: I had a line that was bringing it to focus but not refreshing it. I was able to fix it by adding in the restore function: 'this.mainWindow.show();'